# How can I target an element within a class using less?

Tags: less

I would like to target specific elements within a class using less.

In this case, I would like to target elements of class `button`, but within that I would like to target an anchor tag `a`.

Currently I have:

```
.button {
    /* lots of bits and pieces go here, hence 
    the need to keep it at a class level
    */


    /* further down, but still in .button */
    /* Attempt 1 - fails: compiled = a .button (note the space)
    a& {
         height:20px;
    }

    /* Attempt 2 - fails: compiled = .buttona
    &a {
        height:20px;
    }
}
```

I basically want it to compile to:

```
a.button
```

This is so I can create elements such as:

```
<a class="button">
<button class="button">
```

But slightly alter it when its an anchor. I don't want to throw in the `it's a bug in less!` card too early, but if I use `&.another-class` it works as expected (compiled: `.button.another-class`, but not when targeting elements

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using an old version of less. The code below generates the correct CSS using less 1.3.3

```
.button {
 a& {
    height:20px;
  }
}
```

generates:

```
a.button {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I'm using SimpLESS to compile locally, and it seems that it's only using less v1.3.0 (instead of 1.3.3). If I do use the library directly (1.3.3) the bug has been fixed. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

@Allen Bargi answer is correct, yet only for this specific scenario. I am a little confuse about what you want to achive.

As @Allen Bargi pointed out, this will target "a" lements with a "button" class and generates a

```
.button {
 a& {
    height:20px;
  }
}
```

It generates:

```
a.button {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Meanwhile, this below will target "a" elements contained whitin an element with a "button" class. which seems to me was your original objective.

```
.button {
 a {
    height:20px;
  }
}
```

It generates:

```
.button a {
    height:20px;
}
```

Both solutions migt work fine in this case because you are using the same "button" class for both the parent and the child elements, but they are not targeting the same elements.

I hope this helps.